# fanotify obtaining file name, why /proc/self/fd/"data->fd"?

Tags: linux, filenames, fanotify

I'm examining the source code of the current fatrace.

The main loop calling fanotify to obtain the value of data looks like:

```
    res = read (fan_fd, buffer, 4096);
    ...
    data = (struct fanotify_event_metadata *) buffer;
    while (FAN_EVENT_OK (data, res)) {
        ...
        data = FAN_EVENT_NEXT (data, res);
    }
```

When it gets to extracting the filename associated with an event, the code looks like this:

```
   snprintf (printbuf, sizeof (printbuf), "/proc/self/fd/%i", data->fd);
   len = readlink (printbuf, pathname, sizeof (pathname));
```

I am confused why the filename is extracted from `/proc/self/fd/"data->fd"` and not `/proc/"data->pid"/fd/"data->fd"`?

Comment: Is this a subjective question? Both are the same; in one case the OS substitutes the PID and in the other case the programmer does.

Comment: Are they the same? My understanding is that /proc/self/fd/"fd" would refer to a file in the process calling snprintf. But data->pid refers to the process generating the fan_event, which may be the same, but generally isn't.

Comment: @MSalters both are not the same. `data->pid` is not the pid of the current process, but the pid of the process that had the file activity.

Answer (score 2):

It's because `data->pid` is a different process with a different set of file descriptors. The `data->fd` returned by fanotify is valid in the current process, not the one being monitored.